# Proof that alternating series form for Riemann zeta function can be zero.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

The following is an alternative series representation of the Riemann zeta function.

$$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{s}}$$

Unlike the representation $\zeta(s)=\sum 1/n^s$, the above representation is valid for $\sigma>0$ where $s=\sigma+it$.

**Question: Is there a simple proof that this representation can have zeros?**

To be clear, I don't need to show where the zeros are, just that it is possible for this representation to converge to zero for some $s$.

By simple, I mean suitable for an pre-university or early undergraduate audience.

Comment: See the same question on [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13647/why-does-the-riemann-zeta-function-have-non-trivial-zeros). The answers are **not** simple.

Comment: Zeroes of analytic functions are tied in with their logarithm so having a dirichlet series representation  is not really relevant; the Euler product, the functional equation and the growth at infinity are relevant and neither have much to do with the representation  above

Comment: Have you had a chance to think about this further? Do any of the answers on MathOverflow answer your question in a way you understand? It would be nice to have a simpler more intuitive answer on this site.

Comment: hi @JamesArathoon - I've tried to read and re-read the answers in MathOverflow but sadly they are beyond my reach. Agreed - it would be good to have an intuitive answer to the more general question "can the Riemann zeta function have zeros in the right half plane". I agree with Conrad's comment that this particular series form is not worth exploring.

Comment: thanks @Conrad - I am convinced by your logic that the sum form is not helpful in answering questions about zeros.